# Cartopy projection scale not consistent

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, kde-plasma, cartopy

I am using `cartopy` to display a KDE overlayed on a world map. Initially, I was using the `ccrs.PlateCarree` projection with no issues, but the moment I tried to use another projection it seemed to explode the scale of the projection. For reference, I have included an example that you can test on your own machine below (just comment out the two `projec` lines to switch between projections)

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

projec = ccrs.PlateCarree()
#projec = ccrs.InterruptedGoodeHomolosine()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))



ax = fig.add_subplot(projection=projec)

np.random.seed(1)

discrete_points = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(2,400))

kde = gaussian_kde(discrete_points)
x, y = discrete_points
# https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-data-science/9781491912126/ch04.html
resolution = 1
x_step = int((max(x)-min(x))/resolution)
y_step = int((max(y)-min(y))/resolution)
xgrid = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), x_step+1)
ygrid = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), y_step+1)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)
Z = kde.evaluate(np.vstack([Xgrid.ravel(), Ygrid.ravel()]))
Zgrid = Z.reshape(Xgrid.shape)

ext = [min(x)*5, max(x)*5, min(y)*5, max(y)*5]
earth = plt.cm.gist_earth_r

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', 
                                                edgecolor='black', facecolor="none"))

ax.imshow(Zgrid,
    origin='lower', aspect='auto',
    extent=ext,
    alpha=0.8,
    cmap=earth, transform=projec)

ax.axis('on')
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)

ax.set_xlim(-30, 90)
ax.set_ylim(-60, 60)

plt.show()
```

You'll notice that when using the `ccrs.PlateCarree()` projection, the KDE is nicely placed over Africa, however when using the `ccrs.InterruptedGoodeHomolosine()` projection, you can't see the world map at all. This is because the world map is on an enormous scale. Below is an image of both examples:

Plate Carree projection:
[image: Plate Carree projection]

Interrupted Goode Homolosine projection (standard zoom):
[image: no zoom goode]

Interrupted Goode Homolosine projection (zoomed out):

[image: zoom goode]

If anyone could explain why this is occurring, and how to fix it so I can plot the same data on different projections, that would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I would also like to specify that I tried adding `transform=projec` to line 37 in the example I included, namely:

```
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', 
                                                edgecolor='black', facecolor="none", transform=projec))
```

However this did not help. In fact, it seemed upon adding this the world map no longer appeared at all.

EDIT:

In response to JohanC's answer, this is the plot I get when using that code:

[image: JohanC plot zoomed in]

And zoomed out:

[image: JohanC plot zoomed out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments on your plots:

**Plot1**: (the reference map)

- projection: PlateCarree projection
- (Zgrid) image extents cover (approx) square area, about 40 degrees on each side
- image's lower-left corner is at lat/long: (0,0)

**Plot2**

Q: Why the topo features are not shown on the map?

A: The plot covers very small area that does not include any of them.

- projection: InterruptedGoodeHomolosine
- the image data, Zgrid is declared to fit within grid (mapprojection) coordinates (unit: meters)
- the map is plotted within a small extents of a few meters in both x and y, and aspect ratio is not equal.

**Plot3**

Q: Why the Zgrid image are not seen on the map?

A: The plot covers very large area that the image become too small to plot.

- projection: InterruptedGoodeHomolosine projection
- the (Zgrid) image extent is very small, not visible at this scale
- the map is plotted within a large extents, and aspect ratio is not equal.

The remedies (for Plot2 and 3)

- Zgrid need proper transformation from lat/long to the axes' projection coordinates
- map's extents also need to be transformed and set appropriately
- the aspect ratio must be set 'equal', to prevent unequal stretches in x and y

About 'gridlines' plots

- useful for location reference
- latitude/parallels: OK with InterruptedGoodeHomolosine in this case
- longitude/meridians: is problematic (dont know how to fix !!)

Here is the modified code that runs and produces the required map.

```
# proposed code

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 12))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.InterruptedGoodeHomolosine())

np.random.seed(1)
discrete_points = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(2,400))

kde = gaussian_kde(discrete_points)
x, y = discrete_points
# https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-data-science/9781491912126/ch04.html
resolution = 1
x_step = int((max(x)-min(x))/resolution)
y_step = int((max(y)-min(y))/resolution)
xgrid = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), x_step+1)
ygrid = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), y_step+1)
Xgrid, Ygrid = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)
Z = kde.evaluate(np.vstack([Xgrid.ravel(), Ygrid.ravel()]))
Zgrid = Z.reshape(Xgrid.shape)

ext = [min(x)*5, max(x)*5, min(y)*5, max(y)*5]
earth = plt.cm.gist_earth_r


ocean110 = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', \
        scale='110m', edgecolor='none', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['water'])
ax.add_feature(ocean110, zorder=-5)

land110 = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '110m', \
        edgecolor='black', facecolor="silver")
ax.add_feature(land110, zorder=5)

# extents used by both Zgrid and axes
ext = [min(x)*5, max(x)*5, min(y)*5, max(y)*5]

# plot the image's data array
# note the options: `extent` and `transform`
ax.imshow(Zgrid,
    origin='lower', aspect='auto',
    extent=ext,  #set image's extent
    alpha=0.75,
    cmap=earth, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    zorder=10)

# set the plot's extent with proper coord transformation
ax.set_extent(ext, ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()
#ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS) #uncomment if you need

ax.gridlines(linestyle=':', linewidth=1, draw_labels=True, dms=True, zorder=30, color='k')
ax.set_aspect('equal')  #make sure the aspect ratio is 1

plt.show()
```

The output map:

[image: interup_proj]

Comment: Thankyou for the in depth answer! This works for the most part, the only issue I'm having is the KDE is about 10x larger than it should be. In my edit I included an example. I directly copy and pasted your code aside from the  `ax.gridlines` line because with my version of cartopy it can't seem to draw them on any projection other than PlateCarree or Mercator.